# Trying to keep the order of the characters

Tags: python

Goal is to calculate the character occurrences and I want to print it in the same order of the original string

Example: `Hello there!`

Print out: `h 2 e 3 l 2 o 1 t 1`

```
s_list = s.lower().replace(" ","")
#print s_list
char_count = {}
for i in range(0, len(s_list)):
    if s_list[i] not in char_count:
        char_count[s_list[i]] = 1
    else: 
        char_count[s_list[i]] += 1

s = " "

for k in char_count:
    if k in char_count:
        s += k + " " + str(char_count[k])
print s
```

but for some reason `!` comes after first character.

Comment: Well, in your Python version dicts don't remember insertion order. Look at the `OrderedCounter` recipe.

Comment: By the way, checking whether `k` is in `char_count` when iterating over the keys `k` of `char_count` is a bit redundant.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing this with minimal changes to your code:

- Use a version of Python with sorted `dict`s, like PyPy, CPython 3.6+ or any Python 3.7+ (thanks [timgeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3620003/timgeb)!). You'll have to change your code slightly because `print` is a function in Python 3.
- Instead of using a `dict`, use a `collections.OrderedDict`:

  ```
  import collections
  s_list = s.lower().replace(" ","")
  #print s_list
  char_count = collections.OrderedDict()
  for i in range(0, len(s_list)):
      ...
  ```

Comment: Or any 3.7+ implementation!

Comment: @timgeb Good point; I forgot it was part of the standard now.

Answer (score 0):

You can just track which chars you've entered with a list, which retains order:

```
s = "Hello there!"
s_list = s.lower().replace(" ","")
#print s_list
char_count = {}
chars = []
for i in range(0, len(s_list)):
    if s_list[i] not in char_count:
        char_count[s_list[i]] = 1
        chars.append(s_list[i])
    else: 
        char_count[s_list[i]] += 1

s2 = " "

for k in chars:
    print(k)
    if k in char_count:
        s2 += k + " " + str(char_count[k])
print(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OrderedDict to preserve the order in dict

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a='Hello there!'

d=OrderedDict()
for i in a.lower():
    if(i not in [' ','!']):
        d[i]=d.get(i,0)+1
for i,c in d.items():
    print(i,c, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in so many ways. One of the simplest ones is to getting help from a second list that keeps characters in ordered way. You code seems like it:

```
s_list = s.lower().replace(" ","")
order_list = []
#print s_list
char_count = {}
for i in range(0, len(s_list)):
    if s_list[i] not in char_count:
        order_list.append(s_list[i])
        char_count[s_list[i]] = 1
    else: 
        char_count[s_list[i]] += 1

s = " "

for k in order_list:
    s += k + " " + str(char_count[k])
print s
```